# Can I join TestNet with Corda Enterprise?

Tags: corda

Can I join the Corda TestNet using Corda Enterprise?

Or is there a restriction or filtering for open-source Corda only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join TestNet with Corda Enterprise. Take a look at these templates for [Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/corda.cordaenterprise?tab=Overview) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/r3-corda/)

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.corda.r3.com/azure-template-guide.html) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-blockchain-applications-with-corda-enterprise-on-aws/)

You'll still need to go [here](https://testnet.corda.network) and signup to get a one time key for TestNet.